# string append in python

Tags: python, append, string-formatting

i am trying to prepend each line of a file with "   (2 spaces/tabs after ") and append with  string- "\r\n"+". the lines of the file before this operation looks like as folllows.

```
        <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 5 items at this level-->
        <!--Optional:-->
        <urn:Account id=\"?\">
           <!--Optional:-->
           ............
           .............
```

I am using the following code,

```
inf=open("req.txt","r")

outf=open("out.txt","w")

for line in inf.readlines():

    outf.write("\"          "+line+"\\r\\n\" +")

inf.close()

outf.close()
```

prepending is happening as expected but appending is not happening properly. Final result was all lines were prepended with - \r\n" +"  except the first line. first line was prepended with only "      .

I want each line prepended with "   and appended with "\r\n"+"

Comment: Just a comment: readlines() is quite inefficient for large files -- just iterate over the file object itself instead.

Comment: how to do that, please give sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use python's built in string formatting.

```
outf.write("%s%s%s" % ('"          ', line, '\r\n" +'))
```

However! You're not removing the newlines from your data before changing it.  As a result you're getting your format, the entire line (including the newline) and then your second part.

You'll want to run it through python's built in `rstrip` method.

```
outf.write("%s%s%s" % ('"          ', line.rstrip(), '\r\n" +'))
```

One thing you want to watch out for is that rstrip will remove any white space, if you want to remove just newlines then you can use:

```
outf.write("%s%s%s" % ('"          ', line.rstrip("\r\n"), '\r\n" +'))
```

However, once you do this, you'll need to put a new line at the end of your string again.

```
outf.write("%s%s%s%s" % ('"          ', line.rstrip("\r\n"), '\r\n" +', "\r\n"))
```

However!  Depending on your OS your default line ending may be different, to do it correctly you'll want to `import os` then:

```
outf.write("%s%s%s%s" % ('"          ', line.rstrip(os.linesep), '\r\n" +', os.linesep))
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why aren't all `\r\n` replaced with os.linesep?

Comment: You can indeed do that for the parameter to `rstrip` but the 3rd string argument is a literal `\r\n` not a carriage return and a line feed.  In the case of rstrip, it doesn't really matter, because the line ending is either going to be `\r` or `\n` or `\r\n` depending on your OS, but I changed it to be consistent. :)

Comment: The information provided by OmnipotentEntity is useful for me but the code given did not work for me. but the below code worked for me.

Comment: l = '"%s\\r\\n"+\n' %(line[:-1])
 outf.write(l)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are not using a xml module to read/write the xml file? Because it could simplify your code.

Edit:
Here's a [PyMOTW ElementTree](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/xml/etree/ElementTree/parse.html) tutorial, and the Docs [python.org/xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: really i do not know about that module